# LogIn in Asp.Net Identity project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I'm doing an Web Application based on Asp.Net, and the login system based on Identity Framework. The problem that I'm getting is a bit strange.

I run the application that takes me to the login page, I login (and redirected to the homepage) then if I logout and try to login again it keeps giving me the Login page instead the Home page, but if I do this second Login with a BreakPoint in the async call and then go step by step the login is done and I'm redirected to the Home page.

The code is:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> LogIn(LogInModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }
         //BreakPoint
         var user = await userManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);

            if (user != null)
            {
                var identity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(
                    user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

                SignIn(user);

                return Redirect(GetRedirectUrl(model.ReturnUrl));
            }

            // user authN failed
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid email or password");
            return View();
        }

     private string GetRedirectUrl(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) || !Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Url.Action("index", "home");
        }

        return returnUrl;
    }

    private async Task SignIn(IdentityUser user)
    {
        var identity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(
            user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        GetAuthenticationManager().SignIn(identity);
    }

    private IAuthenticationManager GetAuthenticationManager()
    {
        var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
        return ctx.Authentication;
    }

    public ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
        var authManager = ctx.Authentication;
        Session.Abandon();

        authManager.SignOut("ApplicationCookie");
        return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Login");
    }
```

Comment: have you checked redirect url when trying to login again?

Comment: Yes and it have the home/infex